# How to write recursive SQL query when there is cyclic relationships in table?

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I'm encountering the cyclic relationships while defining my recursive SQL view in Oracle SQL Developer, and I looked up a little but haven't found any valid solution to solve it.

I put an example data down here for your reference, if you can walk through this example while explaining my question, I will be really appreciated!

So the question is writing a query (by using recursion) to find all the pairs (Major, Minor) that for each of this kind of pair, Minor will be Major's direct or indirect Minor. And there will be cyclic relationships appeared. For example, you can have a cycle as: P1 -> P4 -> P2 -> P3 -> P1 -> P4 ...

**Update:** I should make my problem more clear. I am trying to learn a way to write a legit recursive SQL query **(without using CYCLE/NO CYCLE)** to solve this problem.

[image: Parts relation]

**And the result I expected should be roughly as the following:**

[image: Expected Result]

If there is no cyclic relationship exists, I will use the query as the following:

```sql
WITH PartsPair(ma, mi) AS (
  (SELECT Major as ma, Minor as mi FROM Parts)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT a1.Major, a2.Minor
   FROM PartsPair a1, Parts a2
   WHERE a1.Minor = a2.Major)
)
SELECT *
FROM PartsPair;
```

But now there is cyclic relationships, so is there any way to add small changes to my above query without using CYCLE, NO CYCLE to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add your expected result as well.

Comment: Hi, I just added the expected result and more clarification about the expected method for solving it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOCYCLE` in your hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( major ) AS major,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( major ) || SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( minor, ',' ) AS path,
       minor,
       quantity
FROM   table_name
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR minor = major
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( major, minor, quantity ) AS
SELECT 'p1', 'p2', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'p1', 'p3', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'p1', 'p4', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'p2', 'p3', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'p3', 'p5', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'p3', 'p1', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'p4', 'p2', 4 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs all the `major`s and the paths to the possible `minor`s that can be reached (without endlessly following cycles):

> ```
> MAJOR | PATH              | MINOR | QUANTITY
> :---- | :---------------- | :---- | -------:
> p1    | p1,p2             | p2    |        2
> p1    | p1,p2,p3          | p3    |        3
> p1    | p1,p2,p3,p5       | p5    |        2
> p1    | p1,p2,p3,p1       | p1    |        3
> p1    | p1,p2,p3,p1,p4    | p4    |        2
> p1    | p1,p3             | p3    |        3
> p1    | p1,p3,p5          | p5    |        2
> p1    | p1,p3,p1          | p1    |        3
> p1    | p1,p3,p1,p2       | p2    |        2
> p1    | p1,p3,p1,p4       | p4    |        2
> p1    | p1,p3,p1,p4,p2    | p2    |        4
> p1    | p1,p4             | p4    |        2
> p1    | p1,p4,p2          | p2    |        4
> p1    | p1,p4,p2,p3       | p3    |        3
> p1    | p1,p4,p2,p3,p5    | p5    |        2
> p1    | p1,p4,p2,p3,p1    | p1    |        3
> p2    | p2,p3             | p3    |        3
> p2    | p2,p3,p5          | p5    |        2
> p2    | p2,p3,p1          | p1    |        3
> p2    | p2,p3,p1,p2       | p2    |        2
> p2    | p2,p3,p1,p4       | p4    |        2
> p2    | p2,p3,p1,p4,p2    | p2    |        4
> p3    | p3,p5             | p5    |        2
> p3    | p3,p1             | p1    |        3
> p3    | p3,p1,p2          | p2    |        2
> p3    | p3,p1,p2,p3       | p3    |        3
> p3    | p3,p1,p2,p3,p5    | p5    |        2
> p3    | p3,p1,p3          | p3    |        3
> p3    | p3,p1,p3,p5       | p5    |        2
> p3    | p3,p1,p4          | p4    |        2
> p3    | p3,p1,p4,p2       | p2    |        4
> p3    | p3,p1,p4,p2,p3    | p3    |        3
> p3    | p3,p1,p4,p2,p3,p5 | p5    |        2
> p4    | p4,p2             | p2    |        4
> p4    | p4,p2,p3          | p3    |        3
> p4    | p4,p2,p3,p5       | p5    |        2
> p4    | p4,p2,p3,p1       | p1    |        3
> p4    | p4,p2,p3,p1,p4    | p4    |        2
> ```

If you just want the shortest paths to a minor then:

```sql
SELECT major,
       path,
       minor,
       quantity
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( major ) AS major,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT( major ) || SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( minor, ',' ) AS path,
         minor,
         quantity,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (
           PARTITION BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT( major ), minor
           ORDER BY LEVEL ASC
         ) AS rank_by_depth
  FROM   table_name
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
         PRIOR minor = major
)
WHERE  rank_by_depth = 1
ORDER BY major, minor;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> MAJOR | PATH           | MINOR | QUANTITY
> :---- | :------------- | :---- | -------:
> p1    | p1,p3,p1       | p1    |        3
> p1    | p1,p2          | p2    |        2
> p1    | p1,p3          | p3    |        3
> p1    | p1,p4          | p4    |        2
> p1    | p1,p3,p5       | p5    |        2
> p2    | p2,p3,p1       | p1    |        3
> p2    | p2,p3,p1,p2    | p2    |        2
> p2    | p2,p3          | p3    |        3
> p2    | p2,p3,p1,p4    | p4    |        2
> p2    | p2,p3,p5       | p5    |        2
> p3    | p3,p1          | p1    |        3
> p3    | p3,p1,p2       | p2    |        2
> p3    | p3,p1,p3       | p3    |        3
> p3    | p3,p1,p4       | p4    |        2
> p3    | p3,p5          | p5    |        2
> p4    | p4,p2,p3,p1    | p1    |        3
> p4    | p4,p2          | p2    |        4
> p4    | p4,p2,p3       | p3    |        3
> p4    | p4,p2,p3,p1,p4 | p4    |        2
> p4    | p4,p2,p3,p5    | p5    |        2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d701c1b0969ad1198697f99f806246d1)*

---

If you just want the distinct minors reachable from a major then:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( major ) AS major,
       minor
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ROOT( major ) <> minor
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR minor = major
ORDER BY major, minor;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> MAJOR | MINOR
> :---- | :----
> p1    | p2   
> p1    | p3   
> p1    | p4   
> p1    | p5   
> p2    | p1   
> p2    | p3   
> p2    | p4   
> p2    | p5   
> p3    | p1   
> p3    | p2   
> p3    | p4   
> p3    | p5   
> p4    | p1   
> p4    | p2   
> p4    | p3   
> p4    | p5
> ```

You can do the same with a recursive sub-query factoring clause but you also need to include a `CYCLE` expression for that method:

```sql
WITH PartsPair(major, minor) AS (
  SELECT Major, Minor
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT a1.Major, a2.Minor
  FROM   PartsPair a1
         INNER JOIN table_name a2
         ON a1.Minor = a2.Major
)
CYCLE major, minor SET is_cycle TO 1 DEFAULT 0
SELECT DISTINCT major, minor
FROM   PartsPair
WHERE  major <> minor
ORDER BY major, minor;
```

Which outputs the same as the previous query.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e9c65e3d10bc133efcfc2e2db988caf2)*

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I just started to learn the recursive SQL, is there any way that I can make the query simpler by not using CYCLE or NO CYCLE?

Comment: @Allegro You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64469540/edit) your question and tell us what you expect as a result. "Can I make it simpler" is a very broad request; help us by narrowing it down and tell us exactly what you do want.

Comment: Hi, please check again, I just added my original query to this question (assume there is no cyclic relationship) and also the expected result from the correct query.

Comment: @Allegro You can do it with either a hierarchical query or a recursive sub-query factoring clause (as per your update) but in both you need to include a `NOCYCLE`/`CYCLE` clause to stop recursing around cycles. I've added examples of both to my answer.